# Erro no default charset ao importar Dump

Tags: mysql, script, utf-8, powershell

Fiz um script para realizar dump automático de um banco de dados a cada 1 hora com o agendador de tarefas do Windows, porém está dando o seguinte erro quanto eu tento importar o dump no Mysql Workbench:

> **09:53:00 Restoring C: *(caminho).sql***

> **Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="C:\Users\FILIAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpot865hee.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments  < "C: *(caminho).sql*"**

> **Error executing task: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 208: invalid start byte**

> **Operation failed with exitcode 1**

> **Error executing task local variable 'result' referenced before assignment**

> **09:53:01 Import of C: *(caminho)*.sql has finished**

Código do script:

```
#Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass 

$backuppath = "C:\wamp64\dumps"
$date = Get-Date
$timestamp = " " + $date.day + $date.month + $date.year + "_" + $date.hour + $date.minute + $date.second
$backupfile = $backuppath  + "\(backup_) -" + $timestamp +".sql"

C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.36\bin\mysqldump -u User -pPassword DataBase >  $backupfile

# Deleta arquivos antigos
CD $backuppath
dir $backuppath\*.sql | where { ((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).days -gt 1 } | remove-item -force
```

Obs: o arquivo é salvo com extensão .ps1 e convertido em .exe pelo iexpress no Windows.

Obs 2: se o dump for feito manualmente não retorna erro na hora de importar.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma maneira de tentar resolver o problema é utilizar o mesmo `character_set` no esquema do banco de dados que está fazendo o `dump`, no script que está fazendo a "importação" do dump.

Sabendo disto, uma possível solução para o problema é conectar ao esquema do banco de dados que está fazendo o backup (gerando o dump) e verificar o character_set que está em uso, e utilizar este mesmo valor no script que faz a importação do dump.

Segundo a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html) uma maneira de fazer isso é conectar ao esquema e utilizar os seguintes comandos:

```
USE <db_name>;
SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
```

Repare que no comando anterior você deve substituir o valor `<db_name>` pelo nome do seu esquema (schema) de banco de dados.

A saída esperada para este comando é algo deste tipo:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| <meu_caracter_set>       | <meu_collation>      |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

Outra maneira de verificar essa informação é com os seguintes comandos (essas formas são equivalentes, então escolha a que funciona melhor para o seu caso de uso):

```
SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = '<nome_do_esquema_aqui>';
```

Após fazer esta verificação basta substituir o valor retornado da execução em seu script.

```
mysql.exe --default-character-set=<character_set_aqui> --comments < "C: (caminho).sql"
```

Aqui eu omiti alguns parâmetros do seu script para deixar em evidência o character_set a ser utilizado. Mas você pode aproveitar o seu script (contido na pergunta acima) substituindo apenas o valor do argumento passado em `--default-character-set=` pelo valor correto.

Desta forma você pode tentar importar o dump e ter sucesso nesta tarefa.